# How to update specific column with values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called "bug_table" that looks like this:

```
╔════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ timestamp  ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1589649639 ║
║ 2  ║ 1589649639 ║
║ 3  ║ 1589649639 ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

and a table called "bug_revision_table" that looks like this:

```
╔════════╦═════════════════╦════════════╗
║ bug_id ║ value           ║ timestamp  ║
╠════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 1      ║ first revision  ║ 1588587621 ║
║ 1      ║ second revision ║ 1588674021 ║
║ 2      ║ test1           ║ 1588846821 ║
║ 3      ║ rev1            ║ 1589106021 ║
║ 3      ║ rev2            ║ 1589192421 ║
║ 3      ║ rev3            ║ 1589278821 ║
╚════════╩═════════════════╩════════════╝
```

**Now comes the question:**

How can I modify the timestamp of each id from the first table with the *latest/most recent* one from the second table?

As you can see, each bug_id can have multiple revisions with different timestamps. I'm only interested in the latest timestamp.

EDIT:
This is how the table should look afterwards:

```
╔════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ timestamp  ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1588674021 ║
║ 2  ║ 1588846821 ║
║ 3  ║ 1589278821 ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/library/getting-minimum-and-maximum-values

Comment: You shouldn't materialize the time stamp in `bug_table`. For convenience you can create a view that joins the bugs and their maximum timestamp. That way you don't need such `UPDATE`s and avoid possible inconsistencies for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use updated  with join

```
    update bug_table b
    inner join (
        select bug_id, max(timestamp) as max_time
        from  bug_revision_table
        group by bug_id
    ) t on t.bud_id = b.id 
    set b.timestamp = t.max_time
```

or could be you looking for a unique values for all the ids

```
update bug_table b
cross join (
    select max(timestamp) as max_time
    from  bug_revision_table
) t 
set b.timestamp = t.max_time
```

Comment: #1054 - Invalid column 't.timestamp' in 'field list'

Comment: Now the query works, but it only affects a few rows and picks the oldest timestamp instead of the latest one.

Comment: Your comment have not sense to me  .. max(timestamp) is the most recent .. what do you meand the latest ? ..  the most older?  ..and what mean just affect a few  .. rows  ..based on ypur sample should update the 3 r0ws in bu_table  ..   not others ..

Comment: I've provided just a small example. The bug_table has over 100 rows, and only 16 of them are being updated by your query. Also, instead of updating the timestamp of the id in the "bug_table" with the most recent one in the "bug_revision_table", it picks the oldest one.

Comment: e.g.: for id = 3, the timestamp value should be updated to 1589278821, which is the latest date in the bug_revision_table. And I need the query to do this for *all* the rows in the bug_table.

Comment: i'm not in your  db  .. we can just produce answer  based  on the sample you provide  ..  and my answer  should return a result coherent with your sample  .. so .. try post  a sample that cover your problem  ..  anyway remember that SO is question /answer  site and wie can't imagine what you have in your real context.

Comment: The max(timestamp) for  value 3 is  1589278821 and my subquery should return this values ..  try check better ..  or you mean that you want update also the value related  to id 1 and 2 with the value of value 3 (max overall) ??? answer  updated  with this option too

Comment: My bad. I've messed up the table names. The first solution works fine! Thanks!